# using perl how can i automte login to remote linux host using ssh

Tags: ssh, perl

currently, i have statements like :
system("ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root\@${address} \"cat /var/log/messages"");
This did not require a password, since the two systems were setup with proper key exchange

now this is no longer available: hence:

i want to be able to :

1. Login as "admin"
2. Supply a password
3. do a sudo -i
4. supply a password
5. run the same command "cat /var/log/messages"

Thanks,
-Kamal.

Comment: Why would you run 'sudo -i' and then 'cat /var/log/messages'?  Wouldn't it make a lot more sense to just do 'sudo cat /var/log/messages'?  Or, better yet, change /etc/sudoers so admin doesn't need to supply a sudo password.  Or, still even better yet, change the permissions of /var/log/messages and/or the group membership of the admin user so they don't need a password to view /var/log/messages.

Answer (score 4):

When using Perl, **always** look for a module in [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/) for the task. Almost certainly someone has already solved your problem. In this case: [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/Net-SSH-Perl-1.34/).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use sudo, you can probably just add the "admin" user to the group of the /var/log/messages file.  On a typical Debian/Ubuntu system, this would mean adding the "admin" user to the "adm" group, since that is the group of the /var/log/messages file.

To add the admin user to the "adm" group:

```
 sudo adduser admin adm
```

Then, just use ssh without sudo to cat the file.

Another option is to edit your /etc/sudoers file (using visudo) to allow the admin user to run that command without a sudo password.

Answer (score 0):

use [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::OpenSSH).

On the samples directory from the module distribution you will find some scripts automating sudo interaction.